# Retrieve data from User table based on the id from Friends Table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, self-join

I am having 2 tables Users and Friends.

Users Table fields(id,username, password, fname, lname, nickname,etc.,)

Friends Table fields(id, user_id, friend_id)

Now problem is i am trying to access user data based on friends table friends_id.

mysql query is :

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
inner JOIN Friends
ON Users.ID=Friends.Friend_ID;
```

but need all the user data.

Comment: Explain which columns you want in detail

Comment: You're looking for a self referential join, I'll write an answer for you

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [self referential join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :friends,
     class_name: "User", 
     join_table: :friends,
     foreign_key: :user_id, 
     association_foreign_key: :friend_id
end
```

You'll have to change your `friends` table to remove the `id` column (as per the [`has_and_belongs_to_many` guidelines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)):

[image]

It will allow you to call:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :friends, only: [:create, :destroy] #-> url.com/users/:user_id/friends
end

#app/controllers/friends_controller.rb
class FriendsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_user

   def create
      @user.friends << @friend
   end

   def destroy
      @user.friends.delete @friend
   end

   private

   def set_user
      @user   = User.find params[:user_id]
      @friend = User.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT U1.id AS UserId, 
       U1.username AS UserName, 
       U1.fname AS UserFName, 
       U1.lname AS UserLName,
       U2.id AS FriendId, 
       U2.username AS FriendUserName, 
       U2.fname AS FriendFName, 
       U2.lname AS FriendLName
FROM Friends F 
INNER JOIN Users U1 ON F.user_id = U1.id
INNER JOIN Users U2 ON F.Friend_ID = U2.id;
```